# MMS not working on CM9 ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, mms, lg-optimus-one, apn

I have an LG Optimus V (Virgin Mobile) running CyanogenMod 9.  The ROM I am using is located here: https://sites.google.com/site/bobzhomeroms/vm670ics

According to his ChangeLog, MMS should be working, but in reality it's not.

Some Google searching told me that my APN might be the problem.  I dumped the APN XML file from my phone, and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<apns count="1">
  <apn
    name="Virgin Mobile"
    numeric="31000"
    mcc="310"
    mnc="00"
    apn="0"
    user="null"
    server="null"
    password="null"
    proxy="null"
    port=""
    mmsproxy="205.239.233.136"
    mmsport="81"
    mmsprotocol="null"
    mmsc="http://mmsc.vmobl.com:8088/mms?"
    type="mms"
  />
</apns>
```

I also checked my build.prop file, and found these 2 lines:

```
ro.cdma.home.operator.numeric=311490
ro.cdma.home.operator.alpha=Virgin_Mobile
```

All of my research shows that these settings *should* be correct, but I still cannot send or download MMS messages.  What else could be wrong?  I've heard people having luck with replacing the `mms.apk` on their phones, but I don't know which to use, or even where to find a replacement.

**EDIT**: I looked in my `logcat` and I don't think I found anything useful, here's what I found (I tried to only paste certain lines that might be useful):

```
04-17 12:38:38.250 I/ActivityManager(  636): START {cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.MessagingPreferenceActivity} from pid 6064
04-17 12:38:38.599 I/ActivityManager(  636): Displayed com.android.mms/.ui.MessagingPreferenceActivity: +311ms
04-17 12:39:04.539 D/GmsClient( 6089): service broker connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@40f28008
04-17 12:39:04.539 D/GmsClient( 6089): bound to service broker
04-17 12:39:04.539 I/GmsClient( 6089): connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.icing.INDEX_SERVICE }
04-17 12:39:05.469 I/DownloadManager( 5698): Initiating request for download 515
04-17 12:39:05.569 I/Icing   ( 5644): Not enough disk space for indexing
04-17 12:39:05.579 E/Icing   ( 5644): Aborting indexing of corpus 7EC1A9FF78F92A3B7EEEA09B5843349A422D4442
04-17 12:39:07.149 I/DownloadManager( 5698): deleting /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/downloadfile.jpeg
04-17 12:39:37.029 D/WAP PUSH(  940): wpman processMsg 4:application/vnd.wap.mms-message
04-17 12:39:37.069 W/WAP PUSH(  940): no receiver app found for 4:application/vnd.wap.mms-message
04-17 12:39:37.319 D/MmsSmsProvider(  806): getSingleAddressId: insert new canonical_address for xxxxxx, _id=161
04-17 12:39:37.319 D/MmsSmsProvider(  806): getThreadId: create new thread_id for recipients xxxxxxxx
04-17 12:39:37.339 D/MmsSmsProvider(  806): insertThread: created new thread_id 170 for recipientIds xxxxxxx
04-17 12:39:37.409 W/Mms/cache( 6064): RecipientId 161 not in cache!
04-17 12:39:38.009 V/TransactionSettings( 6064): APN setting: MMSC: null looked for: null
04-17 12:39:38.049 D/ConnectivityService(  636): startUsingNetworkFeature reconnecting to 0: enableMMS
04-17 12:39:51.069 I/ActivityManager(  636): START {dat=content://mms-sms/conversations/170 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} from pid 6064
04-17 12:39:51.419 D/Mms/compose( 6064): [1] [initialize] savedInstanceState = null intent = Intent { dat=content://mms-sms/conversations/170 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity } mConversation = [MyEmail@address.com] (tid 170)
04-17 12:39:51.469 D/MMS Input Type( 6064): 64
04-17 12:39:52.229 D/Mms     ( 6064): [586] markAsRead: update read/seen for thread uri: content://mms-sms/conversations/170
04-17 12:39:53.579 V/TransactionSettings( 6064): APN setting: MMSC: null looked for: null
04-17 12:40:53.719 D/ConnectivityService(  636): stopUsingNetworkFeature: teardown net 0: enableMMS
04-17 12:41:16.459 I/ActivityManager(  636): START {dat=content://mms-sms/conversations/170 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} from pid 6064
04-17 12:41:16.649 D/Mms/compose( 6064): [1] [initialize] savedInstanceState = null intent = Intent { dat=content://mms-sms/conversations/170 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity } mConversation = [MyEmail@address.com] (tid 170)
04-17 12:41:16.699 D/MMS Input Type( 6064): 64
04-17 12:41:17.329 I/ActivityManager(  636): Displayed com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity: +758ms
04-17 12:41:20.159 I/ActivityManager(  636): Start proc com.google.android.apps.googlevoice for service com.google.android.apps.googlevoice/.CallLogService: pid=6734 uid=10065 gids={3003, 1015}
04-17 12:41:22.029 W/ActivityManager(  636): Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{414d86a8 com.android.mms/.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}
04-17 12:41:22.059 D/Mms/compose( 6064): [1] [onQueryComplete] onQueryComplete: msg history query result is for threadId 170, but mConversation has threadId 0 starting a new query
04-17 12:41:22.059 D/Mms/compose( 6064): [1] [startMsgListQuery] ##### startMsgListQuery: conversationUri is null, bail!
04-17 12:41:26.829 W/Mms/cache( 6064): RecipientId 79 not in cache!
04-17 12:41:26.839 W/Mms/cache( 6064): RecipientId 79 has empty number!
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138167/discussion-on-question-by-gen-eric-mms-not-working-on-cm9-rom).